# Expand and add a new object to a array inside a function

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm trying to expand and add a new object to a array inside a function and have that array be effected outside the function as well (the arrays pointer is sent as a parameter).

```
void addMedia(Media* medias[], int &nrOfMedias, string title, int publYear, string author, int nrOfPages)
{
    Media** tempArray = new Media*[nrOfMedias +1];
    for(int i = 0; i < nrOfMedias; i++)
    {
        tempArray[i] = medias[i];
    }
    delete [] medias;
    medias = tempArray;
    delete [] tempArray;
    medias[nrOfMedias] = new Book(title, publYear, author, nrOfPages);
    nrOfMedias++;
}
```

This code works great inside the function but when I get outside it the array is still empty. As i understand this it's because the pointer is changed inside the function but how can i expand the array without having it change the pointer?

(I can not change the return data type or the parameters, assignment requirements.)

Comment: Use vectors, and pass them as references. Much, much simpler/safer. (BTW, the second delete in there looks _really_ fishy.)

Comment: *I can not change the return data type or the parameters* Then it's **impossible** to do what you want.

Comment: Yeah, I had to delete my answer that said use vectors because I saw this requirement.

Comment: How is your array defined and allocated outside the function?

Comment: Media** medias = NULL;
 medias = new Media*[0];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do change `medias = tempArray;` to `*medias = tempArray;`, make it compile, polish your memory management (consider, what really should be freed, what not).

Comment: did you mean? *medias = *tempArray; Got it to work with this code and removed delete [] medias; thx.

Comment: No, I mean `*medias = tempArray`, exactly as Rollie answer.

Comment: that give me an error. IntelliSense: a value of type "Media **" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "Media *"

Comment: That's what I meant by "make it compile" :-). See Rollie answer.

Answer (score 2):

Don't view medias as an array of pointers, view it as a pointer to an array. Working example (slightly simplified):

```
class Media
{   
public:
    Media () { m_strTitle = "unknown";}
    string m_strTitle;
};

class Book : public Media
{
public:
    Book(string strTitle) { m_strTitle = strTitle; }
};

void addMedia(Media* medias[], int &nrOfMedias)
{
    Media * tempArray = new Media[nrOfMedias +1];
    for(int i = 0; i < nrOfMedias; i++)
    {
        tempArray[i] = (*medias)[i];
    }
    delete [] *medias;
    (*medias) = tempArray;

    (*medias)[nrOfMedias] = Book("newTitle");
    nrOfMedias++;
}

int main()
{
    int numMedia = 10;
    Media * myArray = new Media[numMedia];
    addMedia(&myArray, numMedia);
    for (int i = 0; i < numMedia; i++)
    {
        cout << i << ") " << myArray[i].m_strTitle << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok thx the code seems to work fine for one problem. I should probably have mention this earlier but Media is a abstract class so it doesn't take well to first line of code in addMedia.

Comment: If that is the case, and you can't change the function signature, I believe it is impossible to alter the passed in medias array.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `delete [] tempArray;`  because `tempArray` actually points to the same memory block as `medias` does after `medias = tempArray;`

Your function will work well whithout that line but I assume that you know what you pass with `Media* medias[]`